# Angular Getting a picture on and on from REST API and displaying it

Tags: angular, image, get, insomnia

I am about creating a site, which will be displaying image took from driving car on a screen of computer in real-time.
I am sending a picture by Insomnia like this (I have not a server, yet):

[image: Insomnia]

and there is a code from Angular:

**video-streaming.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VideoStreamingService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFiles(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url); // 'http://localhost:8080/api/file/all' anykind
  }
}
```

**video-streaming.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { VideoStreamingService } from './video-streaming.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-streaming',
  templateUrl: './video-streaming.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-streaming.component.css']
})
export class VideoStreamingComponent implements OnInit {

  image: any;
  constructor(private videoStreamingService: VideoStreamingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getImage('https://192.168.0.102:8080/image');
  }

  getImage(url: string): void {
    this.videoStreamingService.getFiles(url)
      .subscribe(image => {
        this.image = image;
      });
  }
}
```

and the **HTML template**:

```
<img src={{image}}>
```

Only **ERROR** what I get from console is:

```
GET https://192.168.0.102:8080/image net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

What am I doing wrong?

**@UPDATE**

I did change the line

```
this.getImage('https://192.168.0.102:8080/image');
```

to this:

```
this.getImage('http://localhost:8080/image');
```

and also the address in Insomnia to: http://localhost:8080/image

There are more errors, details below.

Angular errors in console:

[image]

Insomnia errors:

[image]

Comment: Is there any error on the console of backend? Or what is the detailed http error  message ?

Comment: Don't you need to have CORS implementation?

Comment: I am using only Insomnia, i can not implement CORS. Check @update on my post at top. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any service listening at localhost:8080 ?

Comment: What do you see in chrome-console> network tab? Also what do you see when you go to url: http://localhost:8080/image in separate tab in browser?

Comment: There is no such webpage. As I said there is no backend, only Insomnia which contains image as you see on the first screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error of TIMEOUT because the api url provided is not found in the network and it has timed out for the search of it.

This IP address is of the dynamic IP address that is provided by the wifi router.

If you are accessing the image from the local machine use this address

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Don't use https use on http

https is when a domain is secure.

Comment: I do not know how to add a comment with large description so I will edit the Question page